# How to store the result of a multiplication table inside a list in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I tried the below code but it's not working, please help

```
def table(n):
for i in range(1,11):
    print(n*i)
n = int(input("Enter the Number\n"))
a = []
a.append(table(n))
print(a)
```

Comment: you are printing the value, not using return from a function

Comment: indent your code properly. also your function has no return value, thus print(table(n)) is wrong (it will print None at the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table(n)` doesn't return anything. To return you can use `return` or `yield`.

Using `return`.

```
def table(n,lst=[]):
    for i in range(1,11):
        lst=lst+[n*i]
    return lst
n = int(input("Enter the Number\n"))
a=table(n)
```

---

Using `yield`.

```
def table(n):
    for i in range(1,11):
        yield n*i
n=int(input())
a=list(table(table(n))
```

Comment: @user12910547 Glad, I helped you. Mind upvoting?

Comment: Yeah Sure @Ch3steR

Comment: @user12910547 An  upvote is much appreciated and you can do that clicking the up arrow beside my answer.